# Trying to login via database

Tags: login, mysql

As you have probably seen by my somewhat regular postings, I am a newbie to EE.

The company that I work has all of their web sites using EE and some of the sites have not been updated or worked on for years.

Version 2.3.1

I have been asked to update an entry on one particular web site but the credentials for logging into the domain.com/system are not working.

I have access to the db and I have tried to duplicate the member with admin group id = 1, followed by going through the forgot password steps, except this time, it should be going to my email address.

I am not receiving any emails at all from EE to reset

I have made the duplicate entry with the exception of the email address within the table exp_members

Is there somewhere else in the tables that I alter to make this possible?

Is there a way that I can use the salt, crypt_key and password to retrieve the password set by the former admin?

As usual, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on ellislab's forum - [enter link description here](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/192257/#907015)

Thanks for being patient with me

Comment: Hi so glad you got this working.  It's totally fine to post and accept your own answer here, but you could improve it by including the actual solution in addition to the link to the source.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of ways to approach this, but to continue with the method you started...

Each member has an row, not just in exp_members, but also in exp_member_data and exp_member_homepage.  The password reset email may be failing due to a the inability to complete a JOIN on these tables.

So to get your method to work I'd start by making sure you have a matching record in each of these three tables.

Comment: OK, I have followed your suggestion and duplicated the associated id in the two other tables, followed by doing another forgot password attempt, but I still no emails. Is this an issue with v2.3.1?

Comment: Is there any way that I can reconstruct the link that the email sends for the reset - http://example.com/?ACT={AID:Member:reset_password}&id=QECLFADV - I do not know the structure - going by other posts